# Error with rustls crate CertNotValidForName using rumqttc tls with rustls

Tags: rust, mqtt, tls1.2

I'm using rumqttc tls with rustls

```rust
Error = Tls(Io(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificateData("invalid peer certificate: CertNotValidForName") }))
```

this is my function:

```rust
#[cfg(feature = "use-rustls")]
#[tokio::main]
pub async fn test_mqtt() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    use rumqttc::{self, AsyncClient, Key, MqttOptions, TlsConfiguration, Transport};

    let mut mqttoptions = MqttOptions::new("test", "test.test.com", 1000);
    mqttoptions.set_credentials("test", "test");
    mqttoptions.set_keep_alive(std::time::Duration::from_secs(5));

    let ca = include_bytes!("../certs/ca.crt");
    let client_cert = include_bytes!("../certs/client.crt");
    let client_key = include_bytes!("../certs/client.key");

    let transport = Transport::Tls(TlsConfiguration::Simple {
        ca: ca.to_vec(),
        alpn: None,
        client_auth: Some((client_cert.to_vec(), Key::RSA(client_key.to_vec()))),
    });

    mqttoptions.set_transport(transport);

    let (client, mut eventloop) = AsyncClient::new(mqttoptions, 10);

    client.subscribe("test/test/test", QoS::AtMostOnce).await.unwrap();
    client.subscribe("test/test/test/logs", QoS::AtMostOnce).await.unwrap();
    thread::spawn(move || {
            client.publish("test/test/test", QoS::AtLeastOnce, false, "test");
            client.publish("test/test/test/logs", QoS::AtLeastOnce, false, "test");
            thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100));
    });

    loop {
        match eventloop.poll().await {
            Ok(v) => {
                println!("Event = {:?}", v);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Error = {:?}", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

This results in

```bash
2022-11-18 16:11:46 - WARN: Sending fatal alert BadCertificate

Error = Tls(Io(Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: InvalidCertificateData("invalid peer certificate: CertNotValidForName") }))
```

Comment: "CertNotValidForName" suggests the certificate you provided is not valid for "test.test.com:1000" are you sure the cert provided matches that? Could you provide an example cert that shows this behaviour with this code?

Comment: no i simply changed the ip because it's private

Comment: well first TLS certs are not attached to IP address but to an FQDN that may be a problem :)

Comment: (they can be attached to an IP, but that means making sure you have proper SAN entries). What ever you use to connect to the broker (IP or hostname) must be in the certificate the broker presents as either a CN or SAN entry.

Answer (score -1):

The rustls certificate verification through webpki is quite strict. You may circumvent it by implementing a custom ServerCertVerifier.
Take a look at: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rustls-connecting-without-certificate-in-local-network/83822/4